# How was this summation subtracted?

Tags: probability, statistics, summation

So I'm reading an analysis of an approximate counting algorithm. I understand that $Pr[X_{n-1} = i - 1]$ is the probability of $X_{n-1}$ being equal to $i - 1$. While $Pr[X_{n-1} = i]$ is the probability $X_{n-1}$ is equal to i.

However, I don't understand how equation 17 was derived from equation 16. How did the summation being subtracted end up being multiplied by 3?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the sum is over all integers $i$, the sums
$$\sum_i{2^{i-1}Pr[X_{n-1} = i - 1]}$$
and
$$\sum_i{2^{i}Pr[X_{n-1} = i ]}$$
are actually the same. The index of summation is shifted by $1$, but you end up getting all of the same values. Identifying them both with the second sum, this reduces to $4-1=3$ as the coefficient of the sum.

Answer (score 1):

What values does $i$ take in each summation?

$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}2^{i-1}Pr\left[X_{n-1}=i-1\right]=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}2^{i}Pr\left[X_{n-1}=i\right]$$

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is shift the indices on equation (16) over.  Then you can add the probabilities together.

$$\sum_{i-1} 2^{i-1}Pr[X_{n-1} = i-1]$$

You also have to know the starting and ending values in order to shift (look at @SiongthyeGoh's answer).